# Parse stopped initializing (Unity)

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I just work with project as always but now Parse does not want initialize.
I have placed Parse Initialize Behaviour at the very start in Scripts execution order but it does not help and I still getting this error

> InvalidOperationException: Parse must be initialized before making any calls.

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version that you are using?
Do you have init script to share? or is it done by your SDK?

**I found this helpful to me:**
1. Edit->Project Settings->Script Execution Order.
2. Add Parse.ParseInitializeBehaviour.
3. Place it above any script using Parse in the order, or just place it at the top to be sure.

Comment: i see u did not see a picture

Answer (score 0):

And finally i'm done. The problem was in Parse.settings, I have deleted it and now all right!

Comment: can you kindly tell me what exactly have you deleted? I am having the same error